# Do all definite integrals of second-order differentials tend to $0$?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, riemann-integration, differential

A definite integral is defined as a limit of Riemann sums:

$$\int f \;dx:= \lim_{\|P\| \to 0} \Sigma f(c_i)\Delta x_i$$

Would the following be equal to $0$ in all cases?

$$ \int f \;d^2x:= \lim_{\|P\| \to 0} \Sigma f(c_i)(\Delta x_i)^2 = 0?$$

My guess is yes but I don't know how you would rigorously prove this. Consider a parameterization of a curve in 2-space, $c(t):= (x(t), y(t))$. The line integral of a vector-valued function $\vec{f}$ over this curve would be

$$ \int \vec{f}\cdot \; d\vec{s}$$

where $d\vec{s}$ represents a line element. $d\vec{s}$ is taken as $\vec{c}\;'(t) dt$. Wouldn't a better approximation go to the second-order term of the taylor series of $c$? So $d\vec{s} = \vec{c} \;' dt + \vec{c}\; '' (dt)^2$. This makes me think that definite integrals with [higher order differentials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function#Higher-order_differentials) are $0$? Is this reasoning correct? (likewise with change of variables - we only need the Jacobian because the "principal part" of the "change" is what is important. All higher-order terms under an integral sign would tend to $0$?)

Comment: This quantity you wrote is actually not well-defined. You really mean $(dx)^2$, not $d^2x$. Your limit definition clearly does give you $0$ when $f$ is integrable. (Pull out an upper bound $\Delta x_i\le \|P\|$ and the quantity is bounded above in absolute value by $\left(|\int f\,dx| + \epsilon\right)\|P\|$.)